# Obtaining a value from a userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to get a value from this userform to determine the next step to selecting a material.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Material(1, 0)
Dim MaterialC As Variant

Material(0, 0) = "Carbon Steel"
Material(1, 0) = "Stainless Steel"

ComboBox1.List = Material
ComboBox1.Value = Material

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = MaterialC

End Sub
```

Also would really appreciate it if someone could briefly clarify the difference in a sub and a private sub?

I want to use the choice of the 2 materials to present the user with a set of sizes unique to either choice, so I need to know what they chose.

Also, is there a more efficient way of pasting code than adding 4 spaces before each line of code?

Comment: (1) A `Sub` is the same as `Public Sub` which is available in all modules instead of a `Private Sub` which is only available within its own module. (2) You can use the codeblock button in the editor to add the 4 spaces for a whole block. (3) the rest of your question is very unclear to me. You should read [ask] and at least tell us what your code does and what you expect it to do. If screenshots help you to explain, then add screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the `Private` keyword. `Private` is defining the scope of your subroutine, which is that you can only use it inside your `Module`. `Public` means that you can call it from outside the `Module` as well. Since `Public` is the default scope modifier, the difference between a `Sub` and a `Private Sub` is that the `Sub` will be `Public`ly usable, while a `Private Sub` will be kept `Private`.

For more information read [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/5/explaining-private-vs-public-declarations).